# Running scripts in u-boot with qemu on arm

Tags: arm, qemu, u-boot

I'm working with u-boot on ARM using QEMU. I'm using the 'versatilepb' machine since both Linux and u-boot work well with it. I would like to write a [script](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootScripts) to handle some of the boot procedures (set kernel args, calculate CRC's, etc...) - but I can't seem to find how to run my script. I've got the script in memory and I can identify it with u-boot:

```
VersatilePB # iminfo 0x285EC

## Checking Image at 000285ec ...
   Legacy image found
   Image Name:   Test Linux Boot
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Script (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    300 Bytes = 300 Bytes
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Contents:
      Image 0: 292 Bytes = 292 Bytes
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
```

However, I can't figure out how to run it:

```
VersatilePB # run 0x285EC
Unknown command 'run' - try 'help'
VersatilePB # autoscr 0x285EC
Unknown command 'autoscr' - try 'help'
VersatilePB # go 0x285EC
## Starting application at 0x000285EC ...
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x56190526
```

I understand that the last command failed since I have a script image (built using `mkimage -A arm -T script -C none -n "Test Linux Boot" -d myscript.sh ./boot-commands.img`) and not an actual standalone application.

My test script is extremely simple and is just meant to boot a Linux kernel:

```
#Global Variables
FLASH_ADDR=0x34000000
BOOT_ARGS="console=ttyAMA0"

#Now we'll try booting it from the beginning of flash
setenv bootcmd bootm $FLASH_ADDR
setenv bootargs $BOOT_ARGS
```

Typing `bootm 0x34000000` at the u-boot command line successfully boots the Linux kernel

Am I missing something on how to run a u-boot script?

Comment: You should add the version of u-boot that you are using. For the "run" command, verify that CONFIG_CMD_RUN is defined in your configuration. I have no idea about "autoscr" the latest u-boot version available does not use this.

Comment: Verify that CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE is defined in your configuration. http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootCmdGroupExec#Section_5.9.4.1.

Comment: The combination of those options let me do what I would like. Thanks so much! I was trying both u-boot 2013.10 and 2014.1 Would someone like to post an answer for me to accept? I don't want to 'close' it since I still believe it was a valid question for the u-boot novice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer.

You should add the version of u-boot that you are using. For the "run" command, verify that *CONFIG_CMD_RUN* is defined in your configuration. <sup>by [sessyargc.jp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673999/sessyargc-jp)</sup>

The command `autoscr` is enabled by defining *CONFIG_CMD_SOURCE* in your configuration as per [U-boot command documetnation](http://denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootCmdGroupExec#Section_5.9.4.1).  <sup>by [Joe Kul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1821972/joe-kul)</sup>

The scripts do not run as plain *ascii* and must be pre-processed by `mkimage` as per the documentation.